# Long line breaking input structure in VB6

Tags: vb6, vbscript

I have a file that is comma delimited

Text File:

```
"some_key_1", "Translation 1"
"some_key_2", "Translation 2"
"some_key_3", "Translation 3"
"some_key_4", "Translation 4"
"some_key_5", "I am a very long line of text that has decided to cause an issue for the programmer, I have thus far laughed at his futile attempts to fix me."


Private Sub ImportFile()
Dim strEmpFileName As String
Dim intEmpFileNbr As Integer
Dim strTranslationKey As String
Dim strTranslation As String
Dim error As String

strEmpFileName = "C:\Files\test_file_1.asp"
intEmpFileNbr = FreeFile

Open strEmpFileName For Input As #intEmpFileNbr

Do Until EOF(intEmpFileNbr)
    Input #intEmpFileNbr, strTranslationKey, strTranslation
Loop

End Sub
```

The code assigns the lines of text just fine until it gets to some_key_5, even tho there it thinks the text on a new line even tho it is a new line because of word wrap and not me hitting enter.

Is there any way around this?  Shortening the line is not really an option.

Comment: Plain files and the VB line input does not have a word wrap length. If you're getting data split wrongly, there is some other reason, maybe the comma in the value. Try showing us the output of your code and how it is actually breaking.

Comment: I opted to use the file system object and it works just fine with the same data.  It couldn't have been the comma, as it would attach the data from the file to the variable just fine, and include information past the comma.  It would then add the item on the next line as a new key.  I couldn't get past this, tried even removing the commas from the offending item and it would still break.  But after I switched it to the file system object, it works just fine with the same data, i just have to manually split it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted to use the file system object and it works just fine with the same data. It couldn't have been the comma, as it would attach the data from the file to the variable just fine, and include information past the comma. It would then add the item on the next line as a new key. I couldn't get past this, tried even removing the commas from the offending item and it would still break. But after I switched it to the file system object, it works just fine with the same data, i just have to manually split it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the likely problem is the comma in the translation element. I'd suggest your best bet is probably to read the file with the

```
Line Input #my_file, my_string
```

statement and pick it apart by hand. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243392(v=vs.60).aspx) for more.

Comment: I tried this method, but it gave the same error.  The line it is breaking on in my code doesn't have a comma as well.  It will add this to the string:  I am a very long line of text that has decided to cause an issue for the programmer, I have thus far laughed and then the next loop through it will try and add this to the string at his futile attempts to fix me."
for some reason it is wanting to use word wrap as a new line.

Comment: @JamesWilson, I'm slightly surprised by that. I'd imagine then that the word wrap has introduced a newline into the file. But as you say you've found a solution there's no need to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression to match all strings inside "", and then put them into pairs.

As for line breaks, you can simply replace all of them to empty string before doing a regexp match.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have a line termination issue, and you actully have a CR where it stops reading.  I would suggest recreating the file using notepad, or looking at it with a text editor with a hex mode (that might tell you if you have a really long line as as well, if your real file has a line that exceeds a few K it might actually be a problem).

I ran your code against your supplied data, with a msgbox giving the length and right 10 characters of the string, and it worked.  It also worked when I increased the field length of the second part to 721 chars.

Comment: Yeah, it must have been something with the file.  I'm just glad I found a working solution.  Maybe next time, I can dig back into this and figure it out.